# How using dependency injection in a shared library (dll, so)?

Tags: c++, dll, dependency-injection, shared-libraries

Let's say in C++ I have an API in a shared library and I want to inject some dependence in it, at initialization. How can I do that ?

For example, in the calling code :

```
#include "CTest1.h"
#include "CTest2.h"
...
#include "CTest15.h"

class CTest{

int att1;
int att2;

}
```

and in the shared library :

```
#include "CTest.h"

class export CSharedObject{

  void create(CTest* test){ mtest = test; }
  void doSomething(){ int sum = test->att1+test->att2; }


  CTest* mtest;

}
```

How can I inject CTest in CSharedObject ? Just with the include ? But CSharedObject will need all the files CTest needs

I need to avoid all these includes

Answer (score 1):

First, your class needs an interface :

```
class CTestIface
{
  virtual ~CTestIface(){}
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Then in the library add an implementation :

```
class CTest1 : public CTestIface
{
  void foo(){ /*...*/ }
};
```

and c functions to create/delete objects of type CTest11:

```
extern C{
void* Create() { return new CTest1; };
void Delete( void* o ) { delete( (CTest1*) o ); }
}
```

As you can see, you just need a header defining the interface, and functions to create/delete objects.

by the way, in tests, you should use mock classes (inheriting from the interface)

Comment: Actually, you didn't understand what I asked; in your code, CTestIface replaces CSharedObject as interface of the library; But I need to _inject_ CTest in CSharedObject, so the latter can use the former